# Как массово вычислить процент от числа?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется таблица с данными.
Как проще прибавить или вычесть процент из каждого суммы и округлить до 1000?

```html
<div class="table-res">
  <p>монтаж и материалы</p>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Размер, толщина плиты</th>
        <th>200мм, руб.</th>
        <th>250мм, руб.</th>
        <th>300мм, руб.</th>
        <th>350мм, руб.</th>
        <th>400мм, руб.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3 на 4</td>
        <td>68000</td>
        <td>75000</td>
        <td>85000</td>
        <td>95000</td>
        <td>105000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4 на 4</td>
        <td>80000</td>
        <td>90000</td>
        <td>100000</td>
        <td>110000</td>
        <td>120000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5 на 6</td>
        <td>102000</td>
        <td>136000</td>
        <td>165000</td>
        <td>190000</td>
        <td>220000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6 на 6</td>
        <td>136000</td>
        <td>153000</td>
        <td>187000</td>
        <td>221000</td>
        <td>255000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table-res">
  <p>монтаж</p>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>толщина плиты</th>
        <th>200мм, руб.</th>
        <th>250мм, руб.</th>
        <th>300мм, руб.</th>
        <th>350мм, руб.</th>
        <th>400мм, руб.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3 на 4</td>
        <td>38000</td>
        <td>42000</td>
        <td>47000</td>
        <td>53000</td>
        <td>58000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4 на 4</td>
        <td>44000</td>
        <td>50000</td>
        <td>56000</td>
        <td>61000</td>
        <td>67000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5 на 6</td>
        <td>57100</td>
        <td>76100</td>
        <td>92400</td>
        <td>106000</td>
        <td>123000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12 на 12</td>
        <td>276000</td>
        <td>342000</td>
        <td>418000</td>
        <td>485000</td>
        <td>552000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Циклом "бежать" и делать нужные преобразования...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас данные вот так и лежат в таблице, а не выводятся в нее из какого-то другого источника, то да - только циклом по всем им бежать и работать с ними...

```js
const discount = .9; //Делаем скидку на 10% (оставляем 0.9 от изначально цены)

const prices = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); //Получили значения всех td

for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) { //Проходимся по каждому значению
    if (/^\d+$/.test(prices[i].textContent)) { //Проверяем что в текущем значении td есть только цифры (единственный вариант чтобы опознать цена тут или нет. Было бы проще навесь вы какой-нибудь класс всем элементам где цена)
    let number = Number(prices[i].textContent); //Перевели строку в число, хотя это не обязательно, т.к. в js нет строгой типизации. Но лучше пусть будет)
    number = number * discount; //Посчитали с учетом скидки
    number = Math.round(number / 1000) * 1000; //Округлили до тысячи
    prices[i].textContent = number; //Установили новое значение в таблицу
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-res">
      <p>монтаж и материалы</p>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Размер, толщина плиты</th>
            <th>200мм, руб.</th>
            <th>250мм, руб.</th>
            <th>300мм, руб.</th>
            <th>350мм, руб.</th>
            <th>400мм, руб.</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3 на 4</td>
            <td>68000</td>
            <td>75000</td>
            <td>85000</td>
            <td>95000</td>
            <td>105000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4 на 4</td>
            <td>80000</td>
            <td>90000</td>
            <td>100000</td>
            <td>110000</td>
            <td>120000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 на 6</td>
            <td>102000</td>
            <td>136000</td>
            <td>165000</td>
            <td>190000</td>
            <td>220000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6 на 6</td>
            <td>136000</td>
            <td>153000</td>
            <td>187000</td>
            <td>221000</td>
            <td>255000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-res">
      <p>монтаж</p>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>толщина плиты</th>
            <th>200мм, руб.</th>
            <th>250мм, руб.</th>
            <th>300мм, руб.</th>
            <th>350мм, руб.</th>
            <th>400мм, руб.</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3 на 4</td>
            <td>38000</td>
            <td>42000</td>
            <td>47000</td>
            <td>53000</td>
            <td>58000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4 на 4</td>
            <td>44000</td>
            <td>50000</td>
            <td>56000</td>
            <td>61000</td>
            <td>67000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 на 6</td>
            <td>57100</td>
            <td>76100</td>
            <td>92400</td>
            <td>106000</td>
            <td>123000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12 на 12</td>
            <td>276000</td>
            <td>342000</td>
            <td>418000</td>
            <td>485000</td>
            <td>552000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Если прибавить 10% то надо делать `discount = 1.1`? Правильно?

Comment: @steep да, правильно)

Comment: Какой код если я пропишу класс к `td`? А ещё лучше чтобы `.table-res td`

Comment: @steep const prices = document.getElementsByClassName('table-res');